# Use jQuery to uncheck radio button if another is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I can't directly affect the HTML but I can add js/jQuery. On certain conditions this page is loading with 2 radio buttons in a group marked as checked.  Here are the 2 buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="cc" CHECKED>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal_ipn" CHECKED>
```

They do not have IDs and the same name (since they are part of a radio group).

How can I use Jquery/JS to check them?  If both are selected, uncheck the second one?

To Clarify: This code is written out by some (Obviously) flawed PHP elsewhere.  Until I can find and fix that I need a quick solution via JS/jQuery.

Comment: Because they are radio buttons, I don't think both will ever be checked at the same time.

Comment: They can be selected at the same time unless they're in the same radio group.

Comment: If you want to do so, you should probably use checkbox instead of radio button,

Comment: There is some code elsewhere with some flawed logic that is causing the HTML to be written out this way.  Until I can find and fix that I need to circumvent a potential problem this could cause.

Comment: In reality with modern browsers this shouldn't be an issue other than having the wrong radio button selected. When both of these have the checked attribute, the browser will only check the last one.

Comment: I put in a submit function with an alert box that told me the value of payment, and even though the 2nd is visibly checked, the value of the first is being passed...but only when the code comes through as I've listed above with both checked in the code

Comment: Okay, so your problem is, that you just want to remove the attribute checked when they get loaded?

Comment: A better SO question would be to find the underlying code that's causing both buttons to get the checked attribute and fix that, instead of fixing the resultant improper HTML.

Comment: @j08691 that only works, when you have access to the code that creates the html but as op mentioned he doesn't have access to that php code

Comment: Nice call, @Markai . . . that really is the best approach . . . remove the problem before it's presented to the user.

Comment: @ChrisCummings - do you want the radio group to default to the first one, or do you want the user to have to pick between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both can't be checked, even though they both have the "checked" attribute : Live demo

```html
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="cc" CHECKED>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal_ipn" CHECKED>
```

Nevertheless, if you want to force the second to get unchecked, use :

```
$("input[type=radio]:nth-child(2)").prop("checked","false")
```

or :

```
$("input[type=radio]:nth-child(1)").trigger("click")
```

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for editing, dude. I didn't notice my spelling errors.

Answer (score 4):

I might be a little stupid here but radio groups only allow one selection?

**EDIT**

Radio groups only allow one option to be selected at any given time, no JS/jQuery required.

Comment: Please answer the question only if you're planning on actually **answering** to the question. Use comments otherwise.

Comment: In a way I did answer the question and I don't have enough rep to comment on questions.

Comment: @DaveBurns then gain more rep by **answering** questions then you'll be able to comment. There is a reason why you need some reputation before commenting.

Comment: That's not a real answer. OP said that he can't access the HTML directly, so he would have to do that through js and you didn't provide any code.

Comment: I believe that it *is* an answer. In the way the radio buttons are located in the OP's html, they can't be checked both at one time, and such an answer is correct in this context. So I upvoted it.

Comment: @D4V1D ever heard of a rhetorical question? <- That's one too.

Comment: @DaveBurns There's no place for rhetorical question/irony on SO. If you plan on **answering** the question, well then **do** answer to the question...

Comment: @DaveBurns Exactly, you shouldn't answered with a rhetorical question, it should be an answer with an explanation.

Comment: Now Dave you should have enough reputation to comment :)

Comment: This isn't an answer . . . telling the person that they don't have an issue, when they clearly do, doesn't solve anything.  I appreciate that you didn't have the rep to make a comment, but this is not the way to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting second `input` by `value`

```js
$("input[value=paypal_ipn]").prop("checked", false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="cc" CHECKED>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal_ipn" CHECKED>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to set the value by code, do this:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    $("input[type='radio'][name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']").not(this).attr("checked", false);
});
```

But as mentioned by many guys, that shouldn't be necessary

Where the radio buttons get loaded, do this to "unselect" all but the first radio buttons:

```
$("input[type='radio']").not(":first-child").attr("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example:

```html
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cc" CHECKED>
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal_ipn" CHECKED>
```

you actually don't need any js or query, as these radio buttons **have the same name**. Making the radio buttons be of the same name groups them and allows to select only one.

Consider this example:

```html
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cc" CHECKED>
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal_ipn" CHECKED>
    <input type="radio" name="something_else" CHECKED>
```

Two first radio buttons can't be checked at the same time, because they have the same name. The third one is independent, because it has a different name - it can be checked along with one of two other buttons you select.

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing us is fundementally broken HTML (you should **never** have two radio buttons, in the same radio group, checked at the same time), but there is a way that you can work with it . . .

While I don't normally suggest tying a function to the `click` event of a radio button, you could use that here to override the normal functionality for radio buttons and get the behavior that you want.

```
$("[name='payment']").on("click", function() {
    $("[name='payment']").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

With that, no matter which radio button that you check, it will "de-check" both and then check the one that you clicked.

The bizarre thing about this whole answer, is that I don't even have a browser that will show both radio buttons as checked, in order to properly test the scenerio.   LOL

Comment: It doesn't SHOW both checked.  It shows the 2nd checked but on passing to the next page sends the value that the first one is checked.

Comment: I agree its broken code...believe me, I agree.  (I didn't write the PHP code btw)

Comment: @ChrisCummings - Yeah, I just saw your comment in your original post.  The above code will do what you are asking for, but Markai's comment about removing all `checked` properties when the page loads, is really the best approach.

Comment: And, yeah, I assumed that you didn't write the original code . . . I can sympathize **VERY** well with your current situation.   :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have that form for example:

```
<form name="methods" id="methods">
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cc" CHECKED>
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal_ipn" CHECKED>
</form>
```

Get the ID of the whole form, assign it to a variable (var), and extract the radio buttons from it.

```
var methods = document.getElementById('formId').nameOfRadioButton;
methods; //returns all the radio buttons elements

//look for current state of each elment, 
//then loop through the array 'methods'

for (var i=0; i<methods.lenght; i++){
if(methods[i].checked == true){
    //do nothing since you want to uncheck second one
}
else{
if (methods[i+1]).checked == true) {
methods[i+1]).checked == False; //that unchecks the second element
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var len = $('input[value="cc" ]:checked, input[value="paypal_ipn"]:checked').length;

if (len === 2) {
    $('input[value="paypal_ipn"]').data('checked', false);
} else if (len === 0) {
    $('input[value="paypal_ipn"]').data('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var len = $('input[value="cc" ]:checked, input[value="paypal_ipn"]:checked').length;

if (len === 2) {
    $('input[value="paypal_ipn"]').data('checked', false);
} else if (len === 0) {
    $('input[value="cc"]').data('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys if there the inputs have the same name value, when one is checked the other one will be unchecked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
    </form>

    <p><b>Note:</b> When a user clicks on a radio-button, it becomes checked, and all other radio-buttons with equal name become unchecked.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Source:https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio